# Why an external user with guest role cannot access an internal repo when it is granted to?

Tags: gitlab

Why an external user with guest role cannot access an internal repo when it is granted to?

**Objective**

I have a problem giving permissions in gitlab. I want to have **externals** users with guest (role) permissions to download one internal project.

The [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) says the following:

- Users with Guest role can download the project only if it is public or internal.
- Externals users can only access projects to which they are explicitly granted access, thus hiding all other internal or private ones from them. Access can be granted by adding the user as member to the project or group.

**Environment**

I have the next configuration in gitlab:

- One user created as external user named `userexternal`.
- One internal project named `internalproject`.
- The `internalproject` has `userexternal` as member with the guest role.

**Expected behaviour**

`userexternal` can download (`clone`, etc) the `internalproject` because he has access granted.

**Actual behaviour**

`userexternal` cannot download `internalproject`. The page returns a ***403 error (forbidden access).***

```
Cloning into 'internalproject'...
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://userexternal:PASS@example.com/internalproject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply directly to your situation, but we wanted to do something similar with a client. We created [deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#deploy-keys) with read only access to **one** project in our gitlab. Since the ssh keys are only associated to that project and not to a user, they can't touch anything else besides that repo. Mixed with the read only option, they can only pull and clone.

We wanted to keep this user separate from any other account so we created another user within our system with admin capabilities (only drawback), a random password that they won't be given, no ssh login keys, and we ticked the external user checkbox (yeah somehow you can be an external admin?).

Again, not ideal but a workaround... :(

Cheers